# rsync files from remote server to local, and also create local directories

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, command-line-interface, rsync

I have a server that has files on `/files/category/specific/*`.

On my local I have a `~/files` directory. What I want to do is pull `/files/category/specific/*` onto my local into `~/files/something/whatever`. But `something/whatever` doesn't exist, I want rsync to create these local directories as well.

How can I do this with rsync?

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/files/something/whatever && rsync -uai server:/files/category/specific/ ~/files/something/whatever `rsync` won't create what doesn't exist on the source host, and the trailing `/` after `specific` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rsync -a --relative user@remote:/files/category/specific/* ~/files
```

Or You can use ssh to create a directory beforehand or use two rsync commands like this

```
rsync -a --rsync-path=”mkdir -p ~/files/whatever/whatever/ && rsync” user@remote:/files/category/specific/* $source
```

Comment: in the last argument i want to specify something like ~/files/whatever/whatever (these directories dont exist), and have it also build them and put the files there so i dont have to use mkdir -p beforehand. make sense?